# Never ending Thread vs Task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have an application that polls some devices each x second,
my implementation is based on one thread for each device.

Each thread is implemented in this way

```
while(true){
    stopWatch.Start();
    //dowork
    stopWatch.Stop();
    time = (int)(delay - stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    stopWatch.Reset();
    sleep(time);
}
```

Now it's the correct way or i should implement a Timer that fire each x second and create a new Task?

PS: each device has is polling code

Comment: Use a Timer, IMO. You don't need to create a new task then though, I wouldn't have thought. Just write your code in the callback method.

Comment: i should use N timers where N = number of device

Comment: if the work time is more than delay you will sleep negative time ..... timer will be better for you.

Comment: If polling takes too long the program could get stalled. Also using N timers for one repeated task seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Mzf i know it's checked into the code

Comment: @VeNoMiS If your devices are independent then yes, use a timer per device. Although ideally the devices should provide an `Async` API. I guess they don't?

Answer (score 1):

Using a thread that is looping is less work for you and results in clearer code. So I recommend you do just that.

Use timers or async sleeping (`Task.Delay` + `async/await`) if you have *many* threads or need to conserve resources.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. With a timer, you won't need the time computing code, you can just say that it fires every `delay` milliseconds.

Comment: Then you also have to deal with concurrent ticks and reliably stopping the timer when your component is supposed to shut down. And maybe you'd like to keep state across timer ticks. It can get slightly more complicated. Certainly less obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single thread that sleeps between the polls seems like the best way to do this. It will poll the devices needed after the sleep. Since you are doing a single repeated task that is likely to never end until the program ends I don't think that using a task really fits this situation even though it could be used.

Comment: but using a single timer doesn't parallel my polls

Comment: You want all your polls to (possibly) occur at the exact same time? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes, think of it like an istant picture of all the devices, more if a device fail to respond ( and i'm polling 100 device) i can't wait for the timeout to execute the next one

Comment: Oh ok, I would suggest that you try to keep the thread count down and maybe have shorter timeouts. If you have 100 threads the updates might be slower than having 25 of them with 4 devices on each.